# Setting default x axis breaks and title using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, default, x-axis

I am trying to find a way to set the default x axis breaks at 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 when plotting using ggplot, and automatically name the x axis time [days], without having to specify this in every single plot.

is this possible, and how would it be possible?

i have tried running this in the beginning of my script, but it resulted in an error due to infinite recursion:

```
scale_x_continuous<- function(...) {
  scale_x_continuous(..., name = "time [days]", breaks = c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to name your custom function different from `scale_x_continuous`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

scale_x_continuous1 <- function(...) {
  scale_x_continuous(..., name = "time [days]", breaks = c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80))
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous1()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, but let me clarify: is it possible to do this, without having to create a new scale_x_continuous1 function, but by just changing the default for the original scale_x_continuous call?

Comment: Personally I'm not a of overwriting an existing function but of course could you do `scale_x_continuous <- function(...) { ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(..., name = "time [days]", breaks = c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80)) }`